# Old songs not showing up on my new iPhone.

Tags: music

I recently lost my iPhone 4 so I went and bought a new iPhone 4s. I set up my new phone with the same iTunes ID and password that I have always used. I soon realized that whatever songs I had bought on my old phone were not on my new phone. How do I get those songs back? I thought I had subscribed to the cloud but apparently that didn't include my music? All of my old contacts and pictures showed up on my phone but the only music I could get was what was on my computer. Help please! I have quit a few songs missing!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe purchased music is automatically downloaded to a new device, since you might not want all of your music on all of your devices. On your new phone, just go to iTunes Store → More → Purchased → Music and you can re-download everything there.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you've purchased the songs through itunes they should still be available in your purchases. Try redownloading them on your computer and syncing them with your phone that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the songs downloaded on your PC you can re-add them to the iTunes library then sync them with your iPhone but if you don't have them just  go to iTunes and press on iStore go to your purchases and just download them again